# How to check if my table exists bigquery before creating one?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I wish to do something like below:

1. Check if the table exist in a dataset
2. If the table not exist in a dataset then create the table.
3. else upload the table into the current table

code:

```
client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = client.dataset(DATASET)
table_ref = client.table(TABLE)
try:
    # I dont think is good to use pandas.Dataframe.to_gbq so is there an alternate?
    process_df.to_gbq(destination_table='{}.{}'.format(dataset_ref, table_ref),
                      project_id='project_test',
                      if_exists='append')

except:
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        schema=[
            bigquery.SchemaField(name="log_id", field_type="STRING"),
            bigquery.SchemaField(name="text", field_type="STRING"),
            bigquery.SchemaField(name="date", field_type="INTEGER"),
            bigquery.SchemaField(name="word", field_type="STRING"),
            bigquery.SchemaField(name="hinshi", field_type="STRING"),
            bigquery.SchemaField(name="type", field_type="STRING"),
        ]
    )
    client.load_table_from_dataframe(process_df, table_ref, job_config=job_config).result()
```

My above method does not perform it well and its not a clean way of doing my task. Could anyone assist me?

Comment: Can anyone assist please, I could not find the right way to do it.

Comment: I think my answer below will help you do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate on what is not expected? From [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_gbq.html), 'append' is exactly what you described.

> if_exists str, default ‘fail’
>
> 'append'
>
> If table exists, insert data. Create if does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can check if a bigquery table exists, create the table if it doesn't exist, and upload a pandas dataframe into a bigquery table.

I'm assuming you have a pandas dataframe since that's what you had in your question. However, just an FYI, you can directly do a bigquery query and save it directly to a table which is way more efficient because you would skip having to fit the data on your computer as a dataframe.

```
client = bigquery.Client()

table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"


# Check if the table exists
try:
    client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
    print("Table {} already exists.".format(table_id))
# Create the bigquery table if it doesn't exist.
except:
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField(name="log_id", field_type="STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField(name="text", field_type="STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField(name="date", field_type="INTEGER"),
        bigquery.SchemaField(name="word", field_type="STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField(name="hinshi", field_type="STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField(name="type", field_type="STRING"),
        ]
    table = bigquery.Table(table_id, schema=schema)
    table = client.create_table(table)  # Make an API request.
    print(
        "Created table {}.{}.{}".format(table.project, table.dataset_id, table.table_id)
    )


# Load a pandas dataframe to the big query table
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        schema=[
            bigquery.SchemaField(name="log_id", field_type="STRING"),
            bigquery.SchemaField(name="text", field_type="STRING"),
            bigquery.SchemaField(name="date", field_type="INTEGER"),
            bigquery.SchemaField(name="word", field_type="STRING"),
            bigquery.SchemaField(name="hinshi", field_type="STRING"),
            bigquery.SchemaField(name="type", field_type="STRING"),
        ]
    )

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(process_df, table_id, job_config=job_config)
job.result() # Wait for the job to complete.

table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print(
    "Loaded {} rows and {} columns to {}".format(
        table.num_rows, len(table.schema), table_id
    )
)
```